# django rest framework add field when not in list view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django Rest Framework and I'd like to be able to add extra detail to the serializer when a single object is returned, which would be left out of the list view.

In the code below I add the celery_state field to the TestModelSerializer, but I'd only like this field to be added when its returning a single object, not when it's returning the list of TestModel data.

I've looked at the list_serializer_class option but it seems to just use the original model serializer so it will always still include the field even if I try to exclude from there.

What are my options?

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    celery_state = serializers.CharField(source='celery_state', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
    model = TestModel



class TestModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows TestModels to be viewed or edited.
    """
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestModelSerializer
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the serializer class (used by the viewsets) passes `many` argument, you can use that to control the fields output:

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('many', False):
            self.fields.pop('celery_state')
```

Comment: Looks promising - I tried something similar thinking this would work. I'll test this.

Comment: looks like the `many` argument is not always passed ... however the `many_init` override worked for me...

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @mariodev answer:

The other possibility is to override many_init static method in serializer. Acording comments in thie code (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L128 ) it is suggested variant.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ExtendedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  ...
  @classmethod
  def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['child'] = cls()
    kwargs['child'].fields.pop('extractedFiled')
    return serializers.ListSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an extra serializer called `ExtendedTestModelSerializer` which would contain the extra fields that you want.

After that, you can use the `get_serializer_class` method to decide which serializer is used based on `request.action` -

```
class TestModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows TestModels to be viewed or edited.
    """
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    # serializer_class = TestModelSerializer

    get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.action == 'list':
            return TestModelSerializer
        return ExtendedTestModelSerializer
```